# How to place custom menu in user profile

Tags: 7, routes, users, navigation

I have created a user menu as shown below

[image: My Account]

I am using [Edit Profile](http://drupal.org/project/edit_profile) and [Me alias](http://www.drupal.org/project/me) module and the menu system is as below

1. Edit Account : *user/uid/edit*
2. Edit Profile : *user/uid/edit-profile*
3. Logout : *user/logout*

This works fine but I am not able to display it on `http://localhost/user` or `http://localhost/users/uname` (alias to the former url). I wanted to show this menu only on that page.

In the 'Visibility settings' of the block, using 'Only on listed pages' option I tried various like *user*, *users/me*, *http://localhost/user*, *http://localhost/users/me*, but the menu is not appearing on the user page. When I check it with other pages, it works fine. Any idea what might be the cause?

Comment: How Me alias module works? Try printing the page argument `arg(1)` and check what it prints. Set block visibility accordingly.

Comment: it is a real cool module in which instead of using *uid* we can use *me*, so that we dont require to make use of tokens or remember the *uid* of any user.

Comment: What is the page argument `arg(1)` ?

Comment: it is giving the output as `me`

Comment: Have you tried it with a wildcard `*`?  Like `user/*` and `users/*`. Also are you certain the block region exists on the user pages? You might have a custom template file like page--user.tpl.php that doesn't print the region perhaps. Just wild guesses though. Also recommend trying it with the [context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module. It has a "debug" reaction which will tell you which contexts are active when you visit a page.

Comment: Yes, I did try using wildcard chars, but it did not work. And I changed the region to every block which is visible on *user* page but did not get the menu. There is no user.tpl.php page in my theme. I checked the context module, and the debug region shows it is active on the user page, but still not able to get the menu :(

Comment: @Ajit See my answer. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/29722/4471, there are some configuration issues or menu access permission issues for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been searching for this for 2 days now, and decided to go for bounty. But, didn't know the solution was so simple. I tried doing the same on fresh install of Drupal and it worked fine. And kept on adding the modules one by one, again testing the functionality for any change.
It appeared to me that after disabling [Menu token](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token) module, the requirement worked absolutely fine.
Then I checked to see if I gave a wrong token replacement. And the menu structure which i was using was as below

--**My Account** with path *[node:url:absolute]* which i thought would direct to same page.
----**Edit Account** with path *user/me/edit*
----**Edit Account** with path *user/me/edit-profile*
----**Logout** with path *user/logout*

And I used gave the path as *user/** in the *Visibility settings* of the block(highligted of corporate theme) as discussed in question and comments above,

The **Problem identified**(as per me) was that I was considering user profile page as a node which I think now is wrong, so the token *[node:url:absolute]* was actually a wrong token and hence the menu was not displaying on user page. What I did is changed it simply to *[current-page:url]* (as I wanted the user to be on same page, and I suppose we cannot give *#* in the path of the menu to achieve it)as shown in fig below and used the same visibility settings and it worked :)
So, basically the parent menu path was wrong which created the problem. Nevertheless, it was good learning experience!!

[image: My Account menu]

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration will work fine, i hove tried a same scenario.
See attached screenshot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

There is some miss configuration or Module conflict for sure.

Specify the list of modules + theme

Comment: actually, i had tried doing the same thing, with wildcards as well, but the problem was somewhere else. But, I found out the answer here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29534/how-to-place-custom-menu-in-user-profile/29727#29727